# SML use abstype with signatures

Tags: functional-programming, sml, functor, abstract-data-type

I'm writing a library to handle simple images in Standard ML. It should support different types used as colour for each pixel, e.g. bool, Word8.word, etc.

I've got a `abstype 'a image` with all common functions defined independent of representation (`'a` is the colour representation) , but the output formats differ, so I'd like to have different structures.

**Is there a way to "open" an `abstype` inside a structure? I can only get this working in a very ugly way:**

```
abstype 'clr absimage = Image of {width : int, height : int, data : 'clr array array}
with
    fun createFunc (w, h) f = Image {width = w, height = h, data = ...}
    fun createBlank (w, h) clr = createFunc (w, h) (fn _ => clr)
    ...
end
signature IMAGE = sig
    type colour
    type image
    val createFunc : (int * int) -> (int * int -> colour) -> image
    val createBlank : (int * int) -> colour -> image
    ...
    val toBinPPM : image -> string -> unit
end
functor ImageFn(C : sig type colour end) = struct
    open C
    type image = colour absimage
    val createFunc = createFunc
    val createBlank = createBlank   
    ...
end
structure Image8 :> IMAGE = struct
    structure T = ImageFn(struct type colour = Word8.word end)
    open T

    fun toBinPPM img filename = ...
end
```

In particular, the definition of the functor requires to write statements like `val name = name` for all functions defined in the `with ... end` part of `abstype`.

*Or is my approach completely wrong?*

This combination of `abstype` and `signature` is my attempt to recreate OOP's abstract class with common methods from `abstype` and require implementation of other methods in all structures using the `signature`

P.S. Why does SML disallow statements like `open (ImageFn(struct ... end))` and forces to use a temporary structure (`T` in the above code)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason to use `abstype` in today's SML. Consider it deprecated. It is a relict of pre-module times. You can achieve the same effect of hiding the constructors of a type with structures, signatures and sealing (the `:>` operator), but in a more flexible and consistent manner. That also explains why it does not integrate nicely with modules -- it predates them and was essentially replaced by them.

In your concrete example, instead of using `abstype`, simply define `image` as a `datatype` directly in the body of the `ImageFn` functor, and hide its constructors with a signature annotation, like so:

```
signature IMAGE =
sig
  type colour
  type image
  val createFunc : int * int -> (int * int -> colour) -> image
  val createBlank : int * int -> colour -> image
  ...
end

signature IMAGE8 =
sig
  include IMAGE
  val toBinPPM : image -> string -> unit
end

functor ImageFn(type colour) :> IMAGE =
struct
  datatype image = Image of {width : int, height : int, data : colour array array}
  fun createFunc (w, h) f = Image {width = w, height = h, data = ...}
  fun createBlank (w, h) clr = createFunc (w, h) (fn _ => clr)
  ...
end

structure Image8 :> IMAGE8 =
struct
  structure T = ImageFn(type colour = Word8.word)
  open T
  fun toBinPPM img filename = ...
end
```

Edit: In fact, it isn't even necessary in this case to define `image` as a datatype. A plain type would do just as well and makes the code slightly simpler:

```
type image = {width : int, height : int, data : colour array array}
```

As for your PS question: yeah, I don't know either. There is no particular reason. Some SML dialects implement it as an extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't realised you could use `:>` with functors. Declaring image as a datatype is just something leftover from the old implementation forced on me by a distantly-related uni task